# How to add Mac-specific gems to bundle on Mac but not on Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm developing a Rails app on a Mac, and I'm new to testing, so I just added these gems to my **Gemfile**:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'     
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
end
```

But my production server runs Linux, so even if they aren't grouped in `:production`, bundler (*v1.0.21*) still attempts to install them. ...and fails, obviously!
`extconf.rb:19:in '<main>': Only Darwin (Mac OS X) systems are supported (RuntimeError)`

Setting `RAILS_ENV` to production before running `bundle install` *doesn't work*.

It worked by running `bundle install --without development test`, but how can these gems be taken into consideration by bundler only based on your OS?

---

**Edit:** The bundler wiki provides details on how to [use platform as a parameter](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/wiki/Platform-as-a-parameter).
The same solution is given in [bundler issue #663](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/663), so I tried:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'     
  platforms :darwin do
    gem 'rb-fsevent'
    gem 'growl'
  end 
end
```

`bundle install` does not work, but even if we go back to square one and do
`bundle install --without darwin`, the result is `'darwin' is not a valid platform.

The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]`

---

Any other (elegant) approaches?

Comment: But what about platform independency? I hope you still keep in mind this aspect of Rails.

Comment: @MichałCzapko Platform independency is still there for this particular case because there are equivalents for `rb-fsevent`

Comment: `:darwin` is no longer valid as a platform name (if it ever was).

Comment: Btw when it comes to file system events, why not using [`listen`](https://github.com/guard/listen) which is more generic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gemfile actually is a regular ruby file, so you can use something like

```
case RUBY_PLATFORM
when /darwin/
  gem 'foo'
when /win32/
  gem 'bar'
end
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that the contents of your Gemfile.lock will change based on which platform you run the bundle command in. Normally one checks in Gemfile.lock, so this could be a problem...

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only solution available if you HAVE to run cross platform.  We had to do this for some windows / linux incompatibilities.  A simple case or if statement.

Comment: This is okay for gems since you do not check Gemfile.lock in to a gem's repo.

Answer (score 26):

The [Bundler wiki](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/wiki/Platform-as-a-parameter) has a method that **adds all gems to Gemfile.lock** regardless of platform. It sets `require => false` depending on the system so you don't need to be able to actually run the gems:

```
gem 'rb-inotify', :require => RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('linux') && 'rb-inotify'
```

And they provide helper methods to make this clean:

```
def os_is(re)
  RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ re
end

gem 'rb-fsevent', "~> 0.9.3", platforms: :ruby, install_if: os_is(/darwin/)
gem 'rb-inotify', "~> 0.8.8", platforms: :ruby, install_if: os_is(/linux/)
gem 'wdm',        "~> 0.1.0", platforms: [:mswin, :mingw. :x64_mingw], install_if: os_is(/mingw|mswin/i)
```

On my Windows 7 x64 system running Ubuntu 12.04 in a Vagrant VM, this worked fine, but the `:platforms` setting was required - the Linux bundler choked on the 'win32console' gem:

```
Console.c:1:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This solved my problem with capistrano 3 which relies on Gemfile.lock

Comment: The bundler wiki doesn't seem to exist anymore, has it (or that page) moved anywhere else?

Comment: Hmm, I can't find it in the new website structure. The most relevant page I could find was http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html

Comment: I don't think you understand how `require` works. It only controls whether a gem is automatically `require`d or which file to `require`, not whether bundler is installed or not. Gems with native extensions for the wrong `host_os` will still be installed, and may fail. https://bundler.io/gemfile.html `install_if` coming in Bundler 2 will do what you want. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/3611 It might be helpful if there were `install_if: :darwin`, `install_if: :windows`, `install_if: :linux` syntax.

Comment: Plus, `require: true` will require code of the name of the gem (default behavior). (Fixed answer.)

Answer (score 7):

@zed_0xff: found a similar approach in an [older `rspec-core` commit](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/91ff9a29177715cc137c91f9669fff7b85e72dda):

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
  gem 'foo'
end
```

Comment: It's totally unsuitable for typical applications. That said, it's OK when you don't check Gemfile.lock into repository, as it happens in gem development.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `:install_if` method which accepts arbitrary lambda.

Following example comes directly from Gemfile's man pages:

```
install_if -> { RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/ } do
  gem "pasteboard"
end
```

It is much better than control flow constructs (e.g. `if`) as it maintains dependencies correctly and keeps Gemfile.lock uniform on all machines.

Comment: This is actually the only correct answer which creates a proper Gemfile.lock. Ruby conditionals confuse bundler in some operations (`bundle package`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-), you need to use the `platforms` directive:

```
#Gemfile
platforms :mswin do
  gem "x"
end

gem "weakling",   :platforms => :jruby
gem "ruby-debug", :platforms => :mri_18
gem "nokogiri",   :platforms => [:mri_18, :jruby]
```

There are a number of Gemfile platforms:

> **ruby**
>   C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
>
> **ruby_18**
>   ruby AND version 1.8
>
> **ruby_19**
>   ruby AND version 1.9
>
> **ruby_20**
>   ruby AND version 2.0
>
> **mri**
>   Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
>
> **mri_18**
>   mri AND version 1.8
>
> **mri_19**
>   mri AND version 1.9
>
> **mri_20**
>   mri AND version 2.0 rbx Same as ruby, but
>   only Rubinius (not MRI
>
> **jruby**
>   JRuby
>
> **mswin**
>   Windows
>
> **mingw**
>   Windows 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller)
>
> **mingw_18**
>   mingw AND version 1.8
>
> **mingw_19**
>   mingw AND version 1.9 mingw_20 mingw AND version 2.0

Comment: That only works if you have different gems. If you want different platform versions of the same gem, Bundler will tank your deployment.

Comment: Is there a way to know this platform in your rspecs?