# how can i run bundle install elsewhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (61/61), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 16.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       * rails_12factor
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       * rails_12factor
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:obscure-reaches-5507.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:obscure-reaches-5507.git'
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you push your lock file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundler: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513623/bundler-you-are-trying-to-install-in-deployment-mode-after-changing-your-gemfil)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is bacause you commit bad Gemfile.lock (pg and rails_12factor gems) to heroku server. You need to update Gemfile.lock on heroku.

Do following steps:

1. save HEROKU_APP_NAME of existing heroku app ( HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com )
2. remove heroku application from https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps and create new one
3. rename new heroku app to old HEROKU_APP_NAME
4. remove Gemfile.lock from your git repo
5. remove Gemfile.lock form your local project and form .gitignore (if it exist there)
6. run bundle install
7. commit changes to git repo ( new created Gemfile.lock )
8. run git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

In your gem file you can add all the required gems along with rails_12factor and try

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'rails_serve_static_assets','~> 0.0.4', group: :production

gem 'rails_stdout_logging','~> 0.0.3',group: :production
```