# error while deploying diaspora on heroku Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, diaspora

i am trying to deploy diaspora on heroku but getting this error while deploying am using rails 4.1.8 with ruby 2.0.0 on ubuntu 14.04 I had tried `bundle update` but it doesn't worked..any solution..??

```
> ahmed@ahmed-desktop:~/diaspora$ git push -u heroku heroku:master
> Counting objects: 132081, done.
> Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (29619/29619), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (132081/132081), 91.87 MiB | 163.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 132081 (delta 101146), reused 132070 (delta 101138)
> remote: Compressing source files... done.
> remote: Building source:
> remote:
> remote: -----> Deleting 6 files matching .slugignore patterns.
> remote: -----> Ruby app detected
> remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
> remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
> remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
> remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path
> vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
> remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
> remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
> remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
> remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
> remote:        * mysql2 (= 0.3.16)
> remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment
> mode after changing
> remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
> remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
> remote:
> remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
> remote:        * mysql2 (= 0.3.16)
> remote:  !
> remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
> remote:  !
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
> remote:
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !    Push rejected to reddodo.
> remote:
> To https://git.heroku.com/reddodo.git
>  ! [remote rejected] heroku -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/reddodo.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped part of the [installation instructions](https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Heroku), namely:

> We need to switch the Gemfile.lock to PostgreSQL. Edit `Gemfile` and change `ENV['DB'] ||= 'mysql'` to `ENV['DB'] ||= 'postgres'`. Then run:
>
> ```
> bundle --without development test heroku production assets
> git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
> git commit -m "switch Gemfile.lock to pg exclusivly"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that heroku does not support mysql out of the box. You will need to switch over to Postgres or use an addon, for example [ClearDB](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb).

Update:
On second thought it is probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513623/bundler-you-are-trying-to-install-in-deployment-mode-after-changing-your-gemfil)

> The error message you're getting regarding Gemfile.lock may be because
>   your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock don't agree with each other. It sounds
>   like you've changed something in your Gemfile since you last ran
>   bundle install (or update). When you bundle install, it updates your
>   Gemfile.lock with any changes you've made to Gemfile.
>
> Make sure you run bundle install locally, and check-in to source
>   control your newly updated Gemfile.lock after that. Then try
>   deploying.
>
> Edit: As recognised in the comments, a conditional in the Gemfile
>   resulted in a valid Gemfile.lock on one platform, invalid on another.
>   Providing a :platform flag for these platform-dependent gems in the
>   Gemfile should solve the asymmetry.
>
> ~ Edd Morgan

Comment: can you please explain me what i have to do

Comment: try running "bundle install" locally and then commit those changes (if any) to heroku